# Python: pool.map_async with multiple parameters

Tags: python, pool, filereference

I need some help with python pool.

```
def read_values(entry, second):
 ....

async_output = pool.map_async(partial(read_values, second='second'), string_array)
output_array = async_output.get()
```

The above code is working. I really want the below:

```
logfile = open("./async.log", "a+", 1)

def read_values(entry, second):
 ....

async_output = pool.map_async(partial(read_values, second=logfile), string_array)
output_array = async_output.get()
```

This is not working!

Is it possible to pass an open file reference to a pool?

Comment: Please describe the error beyond "not working" .If there is a traceback, included that.

Comment: You probably have to put the file reference in a `multiprocessing.Manager` so you can share it between the processes.

Comment: The file object won't serialize. You could pass in the file name and let the worker process open it.

Comment: @tdelaney You are correct, that is the reason it is not working.